# sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) function st_geogfromtext(unknown) does not exist

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgis

I'm trying to create a table with geography data using geoalchemy2 with sqlalchemy following the [geoalchemy ORM tutorial](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/0.5.0/orm_tutorial.html)

I have the postgis extension installed on the schema I'm using. The user I'm connecting with is *owner* of the schema.

[image: Screenshot from pgAdmin view]

When I run the python code:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from geoalchemy2 import Geography
import src.config as config

Base = declarative_base()

class Lake(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'lake'
    __table_args__ = ({'schema': 'geobox'})
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    country_iso_code = Column(String(2))
    zone_code = Column(String(45))
    zone_type = Column(String(45))
    zone_test = Column(Geography('POINT'))

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgres://{user}:{pwd}@{host}:{port}/{database}'.format(
    user=config.DbConfig().username,
    pwd=config.DbConfig().password,
    host=config.DbConfig().host,
    port=config.DbConfig().port,
    database=config.DbConfig().database), echo=True)

Lake.__table__.create(engine)
```

I get the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) type "geography" does not exist
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the search_path was not properly set, since the postgis had been installed at the table level and not at the schema level.

Not related to sqlalchemy then. I just needed to change the search_path to let pg find the table where postgis is installed with:

```
ALTER ROLE "my_role_name" SET search_path TO 'my_table_name',"$user",public;
```

(assuming my_table_name is the name of the table where the postgis extension has been installed)